# How to terminate a exe from a c program

Tags: c

I am using a system() to call an executable program(A server) . Now after a certain time I want to terminate this program from my c program itself. Does anyone know how to do this?
OS running:(http://rcn-ee.net/deb/rootfs/precise/ubuntu-12.04-r4-minimal-armhf-2012-07-16.tar.xz)

Comment: Which OS? The simplest way would be using `system` with a killing command instead, but an API function designed for this is a better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a function that gives you more control over the resulting process than `system()` does. However, this would be platform specific.

- For Windows, use `CreateProcess()` which returns a `HANDLE` which you can use later in `TerminateProcess()` to kill the process.
- For Unix, use `fork()` and `exec()` which gives you the pid of the child process, which you can use later in `kill()` to kill the process.

Comment: I am running linux. How do I get the process ID?

Comment: The `fork()` system call creates two processes out of one, returning 0 in the child and the pid of the child in the parent. Search for something like "fork exec tutorial" for examples of how to use these functions.

Comment: I am unable to exit out of the program created by a child process from fork using execv(). I have posted it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606990/unable-to-exit-a-child-process-using-fork.COuld you please take a look at it.

Comment: On Windows, use the second parameter of `WaitForSingleObject` (waiting on the process to finish) to give the program a timeout.