# Unable to exit a child process using fork

Tags: c

I am using the following code to create a child process and then kill it after some time.

```
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child\n");
        system("/usr/bin/./youtube-dl -o hello.mp4 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZcqBgCS74", NULL);

    }
    else {
        printf("Father\n");
        //system("ls");
        printf("PId is %d",pid);
        sleep(10);
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    }
```

The problen is that after 10 seconds the program stops but the youtube-dl process does not . It still keeps continuing. My requirement is that I want to start a process and kill it after a specified amount of time. What exactly am I doing wrong. I observe that the pidof youtube-dl which I am invoking is different from that given to my parent process from fork().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `system()` command forks off a new child process, and suspends the calling process until that child exits.  When you kill your child process, the grand-child process created by `system()` continues running.

Instead of `system()`, use `execl()` which *replaces* the current process with the executed file (under the same PID):

```
else if (pid == 0) {
    execl("/usr/bin/./youtube-dl", "/usr/bin/./youtube-dl", "-o", "hello.mp4", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZcqBgCS74", NULL);
    /* only reached if execl() fails */
    perror("execl");
    _exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `system` function another process is created, whose parent is your child process. You can use `exec` instead of `system` so that the `kill` can signal the right pid.

Answer (score 2):

IF the child process is supposed to only do the youtube download (and nothing more after), you could have simply:

```
 else if (pid == 0) {
    /* chld process */
    execl("/usr/bin/youtube-dl", "youtube-dl", "-o", "hello.mp4",
          "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZcqBgCS74", 
          NULL);
    perror ("youtube-dl exec failed");
    _exit(126);
 }
```